# How to get multiple physical windows for an ssh session?

Tags: ssh

I have an ubuntu desktop that I ssh to from my macbook pro. Frequently, I find myself needing multiple physical windows that are ssh-ed into the desktop, maybe to set up code side-by-side or whatnot. Is there a way I can achieve this without having to ssh and type my password for each physical window?

I do not want to use passphraseless ssh. I do not think GNU screen is what I want here (which is multiple virtual terminals within a single terminal).

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why are you against "passphraseless ssh"? What do you actually *mean* by "passphraseless ssh"?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you may want to look into `ssh-agent`.  This will remember your passwords for a configurable amount of time and allow you to login without a password on subsequent connections after an initial password login.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, SSHv2 supports multiple sessions over the same connection. OpenSSH supports this in the form of "multiplex master".

1. In `~/.ssh/config`, set the socket path template:

   ```
   Host *
       ControlPath ~/.ssh/S.%l.%r@%h:%p
       ControlMaster auto
   ```
2. Enable multiplexed connections:

   - Start a master connection manually by adding `-M` (master) option to `ssh`.

     The combination `ssh -fNM` might be useful, to make the master instantly go to background.

     ```
     $ ssh -fNM <host>
     ```
   - For doing it automatically (only OpenSSH 5.6 and above), set `ControlPersist` in your `~/.ssh/config`:

     ```
     Host *
         ControlPersist 10m
     ```

     With this option, a master connection will be started automatically, and the `-M` option is unnecessary.
3. Additional connections can be opened by simply running `ssh host` in new terminal windows. This also works with `sftp`, `scp`, and anything else that uses SSH.
4. When `ControlPersist` is in use, the master connection will be closed automatically when not needed anymore. (In the example above, `10m` is ten minutes.)

   Otherwise, use `ssh host -O exit` to stop the master manually. This will kill all connections to that host.

For more information, see *ssh(1)* (the `-O` option) and *ssh_config(5)* (`Control*` options).

---

Note: When editing `.ssh/config`, make sure that host-specific sections go first, and `Host *` is the *last* section.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do this using `ssh -Y`. From the ssh man page:

```
 -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not
         subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.
```

So, say you login to the Ubuntu machine like so:

```
$ ssh -Y user@ubuntu
```

You will then have a prompt on the remote machine. Instead of working on that prompt, launch a terminal emulator, such as gnome-terminal, xterm, aterm, terminator etc etc:

```
user@ubuntu $ gnome-terminal &
```

That will then open a gnome-terminal instance that will appear on your mac's screen. You can work there and every time you want a new terminal run `gnome-terminal &` again.

---

Possible problems:

1. Depending on your configuration, you may need to allow access to your X session (on the Mac) by doing:

   ```
   user@mac $ xhosts +
   ```

   You can then undo this by:

   ```
   user@mac $ xhosts -
   ```
2. Check the Ubuntu machine's ssh configuration file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) to make sure that this line is present and not commented:

   ```
   X11Forwarding yes
   ```
3. I think this works out of the box in OS X. If it doesn't you may have to run an X session on your Mac.

Comment: It might be easier to use `ssh -Y`, which is less restricted than `-X`. Also, Mac OS X used to include an X11 server (X11.app), but dropped it from Mountain Lion – it's now a [separate download](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki).

Comment: +1 for -Y, good idea @grawity. As for X11, I just checked with a friend of mine, on his Mac ssh -X worked with no other tweaks. Apparently Mac's window system is configured to accept ssh -X even without a running X server.

Comment: `-X` works but it enables various "security features", which so far have only been only annoying when connecting to your computer... (for example, the Xauth credentials are revoked after 10 minutes with -X, but remain valid for the entire connection with -Y; also, clipboard access is disabled.)

Comment: Answer updated accordingly @grawity. I prefer your answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to export a terminal from your Ubuntu to your Mac.
then all you need to do for another terminal window is something like `xterm &`.

Comment: Heh, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @terdon, only on the idea. You have elaborated the point `:-)` +1